# PaginatedDataTable not scrolling horizontally

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, flutter-datatable

I've tried in many ways to make the layout user friendly. now I'm having issue with

PaginateDatatable is not scrolling horizontally and causes overflow to be hidden like in image.

*Note:* I'm trying to scroll `rows` area without scrolling `Rows per page: ..` area.

[image]

**My Code:**

```
    CustomScrollView(
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Text("title"),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      onAddNewPressed();
                    },
                    child: Row(children: const [
                      Text("Add new"),
                      Icon(Icons.add),
                    ]),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
          pinned: true,
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: PaginatedDataTable(
              columns: cols,
              source: DTS(rows),
              ...
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

**CustomScrollBehavior** class:

```
class CustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior { // A custom scroll behavior allows setting whichever input device types that we want, and in this case, we want mouse and touch support.
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
      };
}
```

I've tried alot of answers on stackoverflow but still not solving in my case.